# Declaring functions in JS: Named and Unamed expression

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function, function-expression

Recentley I began looking into the JS library `Typeahead` as a solution to a predictive search box. However upon looking at the code to implement it I began to look into things a little deeper and it led me to declaring functions in `javascript`.

I understand that there are 3 primary ways of achieving this:

1. Function Declarations
2. Function Expressions
3. Function Construcros

Looking closely at `function expressions` it then led me to `anonymous functions`. My understanding of these is that they are effectively a `function expression` without a name?

My question is around the difference between named function expressions and anonymous functions, why would I opt to using an anonymous function? What are the benefits (if any) to an anonymous function?

If you see below ( I know it's a very VERY simply example) it appears that they pretty much do the exact same thing? I can't seem to differentiate between them.

```
 //Named function expression
   var add = function add(a,b){
       var result = a+b;
       console.log('adding ' + a + ' and ' + b + ' = ' + result);
   }
   add(6,2);

   //Anonymous function expression
   var multiply = function(a,b){
       var result = a*b;
       console.log('multiplying ' + a + ' by ' + b + ' = ' + result);
   };
   multiply(10,6);

   //Named function called immediately
   var divide = function myfunction(a,b){
       var result = a/b;
       console.log('dividing ' + a + ' by ' + b + ' = ' + result);
   }(10,5);

   //Anonymous function called immediately
   var subtract = function (a,b)
   {
       var result = a - b;
       console.log('subtracting ' + b + ' from ' + a + ' = ' + result);
   }(10,5);
```

On a side note this was the question that led me to write this one: [Explanation of Typeahead.js substringMatcher function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33899595/explanation-of-typeahead-js-substringmatcher-function)

In the code the author uses an anonymous function. Anyways I'd really appreciate if someone could clear this up for me. Also before you ask I have indeed googled this and been brought to various different sites outlining the differences but I'd prefer to ask the community here.

Comment: One reason that named function expressions are disliked is that [*IE up to version 8 makes them global variables*](https://kangax.github.io/nfe/#jscript-bugs). Perhaps if that wasn't a feature of browser development for as long as it was when the language was exploding in popularity, you'd see more named expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Named function expressions can call themselves recursively.  Also, their names show up in stack traces which can help with debugging.

Beyond that, it's just a code style thing.

Answer (score 0):

While it's mostly styling it can make a difference depending on how and **when** you need to use your functions (API auth and calls).

With the function expression style `var add = function add(a,b)`, the function doesn't actually get assigned to `add` until it's invoked.

With `function add()`, the function declaration is hoisted and the function assigned to add, immediately.

**In short,** function declarations **can** be called at anytime, and function expressions **can't** be called before they're declared.

**Try this:**

```
add1(5);

var add1 = function(num) {
  return num + 1;
};
```

**Then this:**
    add2(7);

```
function add2(num) {
  return num + 2;
};
```

Comment: You're comparing apples and oranges.  The OP is asking the difference between `var add = function(a,b)` and `var add = function add(a,b)`. _"My question is around the difference between named function expressions and anonymous functions"_  `function add2(num) {...}` is just a regular function, not a named function expression or an anonymous function.

Comment: Ah! I read too fast but it's still applicable. I should have included that anonymous function are just a one shot, won't need to be used again, often passed as callbacks to other functions. And the IIFE's are `(function(prams){})(args)`. 

`function printNum(num, callback){ return callback(num)}`

`printNum(5, function(num){
    console.log(num);
});` // 5